# How to Hide Fields in InfoPath 2010 for NewForm Items?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have created a List in Sharepoint 2010 UI and customised the layout in InfoPath 2010. I now want to set some of the fields NOT to display in the NewForm List entry.  How is this acheived?

I can see that you can set Rules on a Control but I don't see how you can effectively say...

"IF NewForm = TRUE THEN HideControl ELSE DisplayControl"...

Can someone help with this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without an additional field. For a new item, the ID field will not yet have a value. So you just need to create formatting rules for each control and set the control to hidden if the ID field is blank.

Comment: When you say "For a new item, the ID field will not yet have a value", do you mean, because Sharepoint's will be used to give the field a value or at which time is the field receiving one?

Comment: SharePoint will assign an ID when the item is saved for the first time. When you click "Add new item" the data in that form does not have a value for ID.

Comment: Do you know if I can retrieve the Sharepoint's assigned ID after submission within the form? I mean, to assign it to a field

Comment: @Kronos, why don't you start your own question. Explain what you would like to achieve. That will be a lot more useful than hijacking someone else's thread, since it will give you a platform for YOUR question with answers targeted at YOUR issue. Post a link here and I can take a look when I find time, but others will find it, too and will try to help.

Comment: Cause I don't think I need to open a question of my OWN in pro of stack's philosophy of reading OTHERS questions searching for my OWN problems. I'm not hijacking anything, I'm just using a thread I think its useful. By the way, I found what I was looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add an extra field without a control on the form.

Now on the controls that have to be invisible put a formatting rule.
Something like this (IF "Extra Field" is blank) --> Hide this control).
In the formatting rule there is an option to make the control invisible.

The last thing you have to do is add an extra rule, so when you submit the form the field will get a default value.

Next time you open the form the field won't be empty and the hidden controls will be visible again.